# Some map entities cannot be persisted when using different persisence strategies on two cluster nodes

Tags: hazelcast

When I use different persistence strategies on a cluster with two nodes, a minor part of map entities will not be stored. 
What I have concretely done is: 
1. set write-delay-seconds=10 on the first node, set write-delay-seconds=0 on the second node. 
2. start the two nodes one after the other.
3. fill 200 entities in a hazelcast map, that has a corresponding persister implementing MapStore.
4. a certain amount (approx. 1%) of keys will neither be persisted via store() nor via storeAll().

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast expects you to use exact same configuration on all of the nodes in the same cluster. Configuring a map with different map-store strategies on different nodes is not supported. Otherwise you can experience inconsistency and some weird behaviors.